# Google Script not Appending Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to write a little script to make my coworkers and mine lives easier. I am trying to append lines to a spreadsheet based on information entered into a custom form. The code posted below just the doPost block which should be appending the google spreadsheet.

```
function doPost(form) { 
  var PN = form.PartNumber;
  var REV = form.Revision;
  var DATE = form.RevisionDate;
  var DESC = form.Description;
  var NOTE = form.PartNotes;
  var URL = form.myFile.getURL();  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID HERE"); // removed ID for sake of safety (let me be paranoid)
  var sheet = ss.getSheetName('Uploads');
  sheet.appendRow([PN,REV,DATE,DESC,NOTE,URL]);
}
```

I am unsure why it isn't writing to the spreadsheet but it isn't throwing me any errors. If you can offer any insight as to what is wrong I would greatly appreciate it; there are many guides online but most seem to be based on deprecated functions/code/etc.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Two things come to mind: 1) did you check the format of all your form-variables, i.e. are they string(able)? 2) did you check, if "sheet" is properly set? You could try to "sheet.appendRow(["test", "test", "test"]); and see if even that doesn't work

Comment: It does not work. In fact it doesn't even seem like the doPost block is running.

Comment: Google Forms already do this, why do you need code? They auto add form data to a sheet. If you want to customize you can use formulas, filter etc.

Comment: I'm trying to include it myself because I want to have the ability to include file uploads. My goal is to reduce the amount of user error in our tracking systems which stems from our information entry and file upload processes being decoupled. It is very rare that someone forgets do enter the info, but when they do it causes many problems down the road (months later).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using doPost, set up a "On form submit" trigger.

You need to get the namedValues to be able to pull specific values and take the first output.

Also, it should be "getSheetByName('Uploads')" .

As pointed out in the previous answer, it is unclear what you are trying to achieve by "form.myFile.getURL();" If you want to get the form url you might as well create it as a string, as it always stays the same.

Here is a working example of your code:

```
function doPost(form) { 
  var formResponses = form.namedValues;
  var PN = formResponses.PartNumber[0];
  var REV = formResponses.Revision[0];
  var DATE = formResponses.RevisionDate[0];
  var DESC = formResponses.Description[0];
  var NOTE = formResponses.PartNotes[0];

  //var URL = form.myFile.getURL();   //Not sure what you are tyring to get here as form URL will always be the same.
  var URL = "Your form's url";    //You can put the form url in here so it will be pushed in to every row.

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID HERE"); // removed ID for sake of safety (let me be paranoid)
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Uploads');
  sheet.appendRow([PN,REV,DATE,DESC,NOTE,URL]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The form fields are nested in a "parameter" property in the `doPost` parameter.

So, you should access them using:

```
function doPost(form) { 
  var actualForm = form.parameter;
  var PN = actualForm.PartNumber;
  //etc
```

To double check all parameters your receiving and their names, you could append to your sheet everything stringfied, like this:

```
sheet.appendRow([JSON.stringify(form)]);
```

--edit

This `form.myFile.getURL()` also looks odd. I guess another good debugging trick you could do is to wrap everything in a try-catch and email yourself any errors you get. For example:

```
function doPost(form) { 
  try { 
    //all your code
  } catch(err) {
     MailApp.sendMail('yourself@etc', 'doPost error', err+'\n\n'+JSON.stringify(form));
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried these changes to no avail. I also attempted to write to the spreadsheet from one of the other functions that does work but I received an error stating that the spreadsheetapp methods were not recognized. I tried just throwing nonsense "test" strings into the sheet per @RobertStettler but I didn't get anything from that either.

Comment: It's `form.parameter` without the letter `s` on the end.

Comment: Thanks Sandy, fixed it.

Comment: @user3491784 try-catching should get you an email, if it doesn't, try running your code directly in the script editor, maybe with a mock parameter,  you must see an error message.

Comment: "TypeError: Cannot read property "parameter" from undefined.

undefined"

I am getting the error message email now. what I did was assign a var formparas = form.parameter and then assign the other vars as "= formparas.PartNumber" etc.

Comment: This happens probably because you ran the doPost function manually and therefore it got no parameter (like it would if called from the form). When you try your post to your script url from the web, you get no email?

Comment: @HenriqueAbreu  does doPost run when a form is submitted. Can't find anydocs to indicate it does. Does it need the trigger setting. I added an answer to show how to install a trigger.

Comment: @eddy I imagine he developed a custom form and is calling his script's url  for submitting his form. If he is using a Google Form, why appends the data to the spreadsheet anyway? Google Forms already does that.

Answer (score 0):

### On form submit

*onFormSubmit* works. **"doPost"** looks wrong.

Simple example:

```
function Initialize() {

  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();

  for(var i in triggers) {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
  }

  ScriptApp.newTrigger("SendGoogleForm")
  .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet())
  .onFormSubmit()
  .create();

}

function SendGoogleForm(e) 
{  
  try 
  {
```

Full example - Scroll down to the code http://www.labnol.org/internet/google-docs-email-form/20884/ (Note: example sends email)

**Trigger docs:** https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

Notes: I think the problem is doPost, Does it work with google Forms? Never seen it used with google forms.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, thank you everyone who has responded with information thus far. None of the solutions posted here worked for my particular implementation (my implementation is probably to blame, it is very crude), but they definitely set me down the path to a working version of my form which we now lightly use. I have posted some of the code below:

```
function sheetFill(form, link) { 

try { 

var formResponses = form.namedValues;
var toForm = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0];

for (i=0;i < form.PartNumber.length;i++){
    toForm[0] = toForm[0]+form.PartNumber[i];
}
```

... (several for loops later)

```
var d = new Date();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("IDHERE");
var sheet = ss.getCurrentSheet;
ss.appendRow([toForm[0], toForm[1], toForm[2], toForm[3], toForm[4], toForm[5], toForm[6], link, d]);

} catch(err) {
 MailApp.sendEmail('EMAIL', 'doPost error', err+'\n\n'+JSON.stringify(form));
 }
}
```

It is not very versatile or robust and isn't elegant, but it is a starting point.